# Spark: Generate Map Word to List of Similar Words - Need Better Performance

Tags: python, dictionary, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with DNA sequence alignment, and I have a performance issue.

I need to create a dict that maps a word (a sequence of a set length) to a list of all words that are similar as decided by a separate function.

Right now, I am doing the following:

```
all_words_rdd = sc.parallelize([''.join(word) for word in itertools.product(all_letters, repeat=WORD_SIZE)], PARALLELISM)
    all_similar_word_pairs_map = (all_words_rdd.cartesian(all_words_rdd)
                                  .filter(lambda (word1, word2), scoring_matrix=scoring_matrix, threshold_value=threshold_value: areWordsSimilar((word1, word2), scoring_matrix, threshold_value))
                                  .groupByKey()
                                  .mapValues(set)
                                  .collectAsMap())
```

Where `areWordsSimilar` obviously calculates whether the words reach a set similarity threshold.

However, this is horribly slow. It works fine with words of length 3, but once I go any higher it slows down exponentially (as you might expect). It also starts complaining about the task size being too big (again, not surprising)

I know the cartesian join is a really inefficient way to do this, but I'm not sure how to approach it otherwise.

I was thinking of starting with something like this:

```
all_words_rdd = (sc.parallelize(xrange(0, len(all_letters) ** WORD_SIZE))
                     .repartition(PARALLELISM)
                     ...
                     )
```

This would let me split the calculation across multiple nodes. However, how do I calculate this? I was thinking about doing something with bases and inferring the letter using the modulo operator (i.e. in base of len(all_letters), `num % 2 = all_letters[0]`, `num % 3 = all_letters[1]`, etc).

However, this sounds horribly complicated, so I was wondering if anybody had a better way.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
I understand that I cannot reduce the exponential complexity of the problem, that is not my goal. My goal is to break up the complexity across multiple nodes of execution by having each node perform part of the calculation. However, to do this I need to be able to derive a DNA word from a number using some process.

Comment: It is possible to optimize a little but you simply cannot win with exponential complexity. Generating all possible patterns is simply hopeless. There are different heuristics you can try but without a context it is hard to give you a meaningful advice.

Comment: I understand,  but what I am trying to accomplish is to move the complexity to multiple nodes instead of just the master.

Comment: I guess I could just pregenerate these tables for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking even without driver side code it looks like a hopeless task. Size of the sequence set is growing exponentially and you simply cannot win with that. Depending on how you plan to use this data there is most likely a better approach out there.

If you still want to go with this you can start with spiting kmers generation between a driver and workers:

```
from itertools import product

def extend_kmer(n, kmer="", alphabet="ATGC"):
    """
    >>> list(extend_kmer(2))[:4]
    ['AA', 'AT', 'AG', 'AC']
    """
    tails = product(alphabet, repeat=n)
    for tail in tails:
        yield kmer + "".join(tail)


def generate_kmers(k, seed_size,  alphabet="ATGC"):
    """
    >>> kmers = generate_kmers(6, 3, "ATGC").collect()
    >>> len(kmers)
    4096
    >>> sorted(kmers)[0]
    'AAAAAA'
    """
    seed = sc.parallelize([x for x in extend_kmer(seed_size, "", alphabet)])
    return seed.flatMap(lambda kmer: extend_kmer(k - seed_size, kmer, alphabet))


k = ... # Integer
seed_size = ... # Integer <= k
kmers = generate_kmers(k, seed_size) # RDD kmers
```

The simplest optimization you can do when it comes to searching is to drop `cartesian` and use a local generation:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def is_similar(x, y):
    """Dummy similarity check
    >>> is_similar("AAAAA", "AAAAT")
    True
    >>> is_similar("AAAAA", "TTTTTT") 
    False
    """
    return SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio() > 0.75


def find_similar(kmer, f=is_similar, alphabet="ATGC"):
    """
    >>> kmer, similar = find_similar("AAAAAA")
    >>> sorted(similar)[:5]
    ['AAAAAA', 'AAAAAC', 'AAAAAG', 'AAAAAT', 'AAAACA']
    """
    candidates = product(alphabet, repeat=len(kmer))
    return (kmer, {"".join(x) for x in candidates if is_similar(kmer, x)})


 similar_map = kmers.flatmap(find_similar)
```

It is still an extremely naive approach but it doesn't require expensive data shuffling.

Next thing you can try is to improve search strategy. It can be done either locally like above or globally using joins.

In both cases you need a smarter approach than checking all possible kmers. First thing that comes to mind is to use seed kmers taken from a given word. In locally mode these can be used as  a starting point for candidate generation, in a global mode a join key (optionally combined with hashing).

Comment: Yeah, I was talking about this with a few colleagues and I'm really thinking I'm doing this wrong. I need a calculation approach rather than brute force (i.e. derive all similar words from each word rather than checking every single one). Still, this looks like an improvement on what I have done, so I'll mark it accepted.